# How do I convert from Case-Insensitive to case-sensitive in 10.8

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition, filesystem

I just got a new (well refurbished) MacBook Pro running 10.8.3. I am a programmer, so I have need of a case-sensitive filesystem. It is fresh and I am reluctant to upgrade it or do much with it until I can change the partition to be case-sensitive.

To be sure, I ran "diskutil info disk0s2" on it. Under filesystem personality it says "Journaled HFS+". Which I understand to be the case-insensitive format.

I have done a little research and supposedly iPartition can do it, but I am reluctant to buy it because I think it can be done without spending money. Even if it is a more complicated method. And because I just got it, so I am not afraid to reinstall Mac OS X if need be. I would just need a way to do it without a disk.

So, what is the quickest and easiest way to make the partition case-sensitive?

Comment: I bet if you create a Time Machine backup or boot from the installer (and run Disk Utility), you can make a backup of the current system, then format your drive how you want it and load the backup image. BTW - I once installed Case-Sensitive HFS, because, as a developer joining a project, I thought I needed it.. Caused all my builds to break and produced headaches until I reformatted as case-insensitive.

Comment: @Doc What kind of builds where you doing? I am a web developer. So I generally deal with Unix/Linux systems anyway. I have actually had headaches caused by using case-insensitive systems before (Windows and in one case a Mac).

Comment: By the way, you should make that an answer to this question so that I can vote it up and possibly use it as the choice answer if I go that route.

Comment: Why exactly do you need case sensitivity? Usually Unix ports were the main reason and these have mainly been converted to build OK

Comment: I am a web developer. I deal with case sensitive files quite often.

Comment: I was working on a cross-platform C++ application. I do a decent amount of web development now and I've never had a problem with case-insensitive HFS+, though, I'm not developing for OSX (Linux is my target) and thus I don't run web applications on OSX

Comment: I will probably just use VMs for it. I will think about it more. Maybe I can just stick with the VMs for it. I have just always preferred working with case-sensitive formats. It especially avoids problems you can sometimes have when committing to git, hg, or svn (**shivers**).

Comment: This is not recommended if you use any adobe products, they simply won't install on case-sensitive fs on osx.

Comment: That seems like a ridiculous mistake in design. But I do remember using Adobe Acrobat on one awhile ago. Maybe that has changed.

Comment: If you develop on a case sensitive environment, your programs will work without a problem on case sensitive and on case insensitive environment. On the contrary, if you develop in a case insensitive environment, your programs will only work in a case insensitive environment and may fail in a case sensitive environment. (See Adobe software which didn't go through a quality control process: sometimes a file created as `a` is then read as `A` :().

Comment: Moreover from a security standpoint to run a case sensitive environment is a good method to detect bad softwares (like crapwares or poor quality ones): they will simply fail.

Answer (score 3):

I've run in to this before and the only solution I'm aware of is to reformat your file system. Here's what I suggest you do:

1. Boot off of your OSX install media and use Disk Utility to clone your OS image on to another drive.
2. Reformat your main drive with the file system you want
3. Restore the contents of your backed-up system to the main drive.

<strike>You could also go largely through Time Machine for this, but I'd recommend going straight at Disk Utility.</strike> TimeMachine refuses to restore from backups that have a different case-sensitivity setting.

Here's [a random link to someone's article](http://nyacomputing.com/how-to-create-a-bootable-clone-of-your-mac-hard-drive/) on cloning a drive with Disk Utility.

Comment: I will have to look up how to create an install disk from within the OS since it did not come with one.

Comment: pthurmond It's pretty easy if you google it for your version of OS X.